# Missing localization of Ubuntu touch for Slovak language

Tags: application-development, localization

I would like to translate the Ubuntu touch system into Slovak. How to do this ? Where to start ?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Translations/Contact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to start by translating the Ubuntu Touch system is by translating the core apps. You can find them on [launchpad](https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone-coreapps). There are links to the translating pages of the core apps on this overview site.

Please read the [Ubuntu Tranlsation Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Translations/) before you start.